# Remove ability for portrait orientation for app in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, orientation

Is there a way where I can only allow my app viewable in landscape mode? I've managed to default the application's orientation to landscape, however in the iPad simulator, when I do Command->Arrow, the application rotates to portrait. I've removed the listings in the plist under "Supported interface orientations" for both of the Portrait entries, however that doesn't seem to've changed anything.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "rotates to portrait"? You realize there's nothing you can do to stop the user physically rotating the device, right?

Comment: Yes, but some applications are able to lock their orientation to landscape, even if the device is oriented to portrait.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your view controller, there's a delegate method for this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I knew I've seen this line of code before, just forgot about it.

Comment: This is obsolete; this method is deprecated as of iOS 6.

Answer (score 3):

Do a project find for "autorotate", and edit the methods you'll find accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need tell the view that the specified orientation is not supported

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
    (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed with some updates. Currently, you'll simply need to add the following method:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

that will only allow landscape. Turn the phone all you like and it will only stay in either left or right landscape. Have fun :)